# DELETE statement causing exception in ASP web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, detailsview

Not sure why this is not working and looking for any help. I have an ASP web site that I am building. One page is set up as a Master/Detail page where a GridView is used to show the records within a table. A DetailView with the INSERT, UPDATE AND DELETE STATEMENTS is bound to the SELECT button on my GridView.

The INSERT and UPDATE statements work without a problem, however the DELETE statement is throwing an Exception.

Here is the code for handling the Exception.

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemDeleted(object sender, DetailsViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            lblError.Text = "A database error has occurred.<br /><br />" + "Message: " + e.Exception.Message;
            e.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
            lblError.Text = "Another user may have updated that product." + "<br />Please try again.";
        else
            GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The Exception thrown is the e.AffectedRows Exception.

I am not sure why my table is not accepting the DELETE Statement, any ideas would be appreciated. Here is the code for DetailView

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HalloweenConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE [ProductID] = @original_ProductID AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [ShortDescription] = @original_ShortDescription AND [LongDescription] = @original_LongDescription AND [CategoryID] = @original_CategoryID AND (([ImageFile] = @original_ImageFile) OR ([ImageFile] IS NULL AND @original_ImageFile IS NULL)) AND [UnitPrice] = @original_UnitPrice AND [OnHand] = @original_OnHand" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Products] ([ProductID], [Name], [ShortDescription], [LongDescription], [CategoryID], [ImageFile], [UnitPrice], [OnHand]) VALUES (@ProductID, @Name, @ShortDescription, @LongDescription, @CategoryID, @ImageFile, @UnitPrice, @OnHand)" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Name], [ShortDescription], [LongDescription], [CategoryID], [ImageFile], [UnitPrice], [OnHand] FROM [Products] WHERE ([ProductID] = @ProductID)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Products] SET [Name] = @Name, [ShortDescription] = @ShortDescription, [LongDescription] = @LongDescription, [CategoryID] = @CategoryID, [ImageFile] = @ImageFile, [UnitPrice] = @UnitPrice, [OnHand] = @OnHand WHERE [ProductID] = @original_ProductID AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [ShortDescription] = @original_ShortDescription AND [LongDescription] = @original_LongDescription AND [CategoryID] = @original_CategoryID AND (([ImageFile] = @original_ImageFile) OR ([ImageFile] IS NULL AND @original_ImageFile IS NULL)) AND [UnitPrice] = @original_UnitPrice AND [OnHand] = @original_OnHand">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="ProductID" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProductID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ShortDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_LongDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CategoryID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ImageFile" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_OnHand" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ShortDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LongDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ImageFile" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OnHand" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProductID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ShortDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_LongDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CategoryID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ImageFile" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_OnHand" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ShortDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LongDescription" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ImageFile" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OnHand" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: can you rule out a problem with the db first? ie: can you run that delete command via SQL directly?

Comment: The actual stack trace would be much more helpful here.  But, as Kyle C mentions, verifying the query against your DB is the first step...

Comment: If ProductID is unique, you can simplify the WHERE clauses in both DELETE and UPDATE.

Comment: @Brian I don't think there would be a stack stace since the affectedrows is 0. Therefore, the delete condition did not match any records.

Comment: Every exception has a stack trace - `e.Exception.ToString()`

Comment: @jrummell The OP stated that `The Exception thrown is the e.AffectedRows Exception.` but `e.AffectedRows` is not an Exception. The fact that it reached that part of the code means that `e.Exception = null`

Comment: If I got it correct the StackTrace when I clicked the Delete button generated this "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewDeletedEventArgs"

Comment: That is not the stack trace. There is no stack trace - no exception thrown because like what I said before, the fact that it reached that part of the code (`else if (e.AffectedRows == 0)`) means that `e.Exception == null`. So don't call `e.AffectedRows` as Exception because it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd just use the primary key in my `where` clause when deleting (`ProductID`?). The delete statement probably fails in the where condition.

If there are no business rules related to the delete command, can you try this:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE [ProductID] = @original_ProductID"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, somewhere in the WHERE clause the problem occurred. Still not sure why...but your suggestion proved that the delete command works by only specifying the primary key. In the end I re-wrote the page from scratch and the second time around was a charm. As a noob can't say why the first time didn't work (the code from the second attempt looks the same) but it does work and your suggestion helped narrow it down. Thanks everyone for the suggestions.